# geturl but ignore store code

Tags: magento-1.9, php, geturl

Hi I'm trying to replace a link to a cms page "review" in a .phtml file like so:

```
<?php echo $this->getUrl('review'); ?>
```

But this returns www.mydomain/shop/review/ as "shop" is our store view code.

How can I change it to return www.mydomain/review/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php echo $this->getUrl('review', array('_type'=>Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_DIRECT_LINK)); ?>
```